# Firebreath : Is it possible to add /clr support in new plugin created using firebreath project

Tags: .net, clr, firebreath

I have a c# dll. Now i need to call that c# dll from c++ firebreath dll project.

Is it possible to do that

Answer (score 0):

Not to the best of my knowledge, though you can certainly try. Others have, nobody that I know of has succeeded. The recommended method is to create a C++ wrapper dll with /clr that you can link to from a C++ lib that isn't /clr.

Comment: Are you talking about LoadLibrary() function ?

Comment: All DLLs are loaded with LoadLibrary, either by your code or automatically, so I suppose the answer is "yes"